# gpu out of memory when using script + bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

Tags: python, rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am using a python script to render many frames with bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True). However at some point the script says "GPU Out of Memory..." at first I thought it was some specific frames that caused the problem but while rendering again I didn't have the same issue, it appears to be kind of random but after rendering some frames with this method. Do I have to dump the memory or something like that after each render?

Comment: Are you using any addon ?

Comment: Yes, I have some basic add ons like Loom, Node Wrangler, F2, AnimAll, Loop Tools, Principled baker, and probably those are the only ones that I added/activated manually. The only one that works for rendering is Loom but I don't use it or refer to it in my code. Do you think it has something to do?